# typedef struct and pointer

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

When we have:

```
      struct node{.....}
      typedef struct node Node;
      typedef Node *ptr;
```

is ptr a pointer to struct node or typedef changes the meaning of it?

Comment: The third line shouldn't even compile.

Comment: i have seen typedef on pointers a couple of times and i cant understand how to use it

Comment: i have seen it like this

Comment: `node`  is undefined (in C as opposed to C++).

Comment: @mojo Pretty sure you meant `typedef Node *ptr`. C is case-sensitive, so `node` is not the same as `Node`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition

```
typedef struct node *ptr;
```

will make `ptr` an alias for `struct node *`.

Afterwards you can do either

```
struct node *some_pointer;
```

Or

```
ptr some_pointer;
```

Both will define the variable `some_pointer` to be a pointer to the `node` structure.

***But*** making type-aliases of pointer types is not something I recommend. It can make the code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Take for example the most common problem that I've seen here on Stack Overflow when it comes to pointer type aliases:

```
ptr some_pointer = malloc(sizeof(ptr));
```

That allocates memory enough for a *pointer* to the structure, not for the whole structure. If using e.g.

```
Node *some_pointer = malloc(sizeof(Node*));
```

that error would be much clearer and easier to find.

See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)